# Search data from mysql databse and store it in the datagridview

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview

Search data from database when the item is found store it on the datagridview and from there store it to other table in the mysql database and compute the total amount of goods and price . I tried different methods but i feel lost at this point. I have a datagridview and an textbox that searches for the item by barcode.

```
        konekcija.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from baza.artikli where barkod like '%" &TextBox1.Text & "%'"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        SDA.SelectCommand = COMMAND
        SDA.Fill(bazaDataSet)
        bajndsors.DataSource = bazaDataSet
        DataGridView1.DataSource = bajndsors
        SDA.Update(bazaDataSet)
        konekcija.Close()
```

the store in the database code :

```
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "insert into baza.smetka(barkod,naziv,kupovna,prodazna,kolicina,ddv,proizvoditel,opis,profit) values ('" & TextBoxBarkod.Text & "','" & TextBoxNaziv.Text & "','" & kupovnacena & "','" & prodaznacena & "','" & kolicina & "','" & ddv & "','" & TextBoxProizvoditel.Text & "','" & TextBoxOpis.Text & "','" & profit & "')"
        COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(Query, konekcija)
        READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

Comment: Just show us what you have tried via an [edit] so you don't get pounded with downvotes

Comment: QUESTION IS UPDATED

Comment: So what exactly is the problem with the code (other than you are not using SQL parameters, and not disposing of anything?)

Comment: and when i press enter i want to store the data to the mysql database table receipt i have the code

Comment: [edit] your question to add an actual question along with any other relevant code.  That code just selects from the DB, a SELECT statement will not store anything.

Comment: i edited the question

Comment: Gah! The Sql Injection vulnerability. It burns us. Seriously... this code is practically begging to get that DB hacked.